# HTTPS routing is too slow with aws fargate

Tags: amazon-web-services, load-balancing, aws-fargate

I try to serve Django app on aws fargate in https.

I connected my fargate service with network loadbalancers which use secure tcp connection certificated by ACM. And then I configured route 53 record set to connect load-balacer as alias target which made https connection possible.

[image]

It made my https connection possible however it is too slow to use this api in production. It is wokring much more slowly than http requests made with DNS name of loadbalancer. It seems like I have some problem between loadbalancers and route 53 setting but I don't know how to figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

Generally there is no real difference between http and https requests. Could you post you results of http vs https requests. Maybe test it through jmeter while running one fargate service through http, and another through https which the same version of the app running in both places.

Once you get your results, put logs in the tasks to see how fast the actual each request is processed in server side so you'll know for sure which one is faster and slower. It would be a lot more easier for us to help if we had that information.